# $X$ has a normal group $Y$ so $[X: Y]=4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the following set: $$X = \{\sigma \in S_6 | \sigma(k) \ is \ odd\ if\ and\ only\ if \ k \ is \ odd\}.$$

I would like to show that $X$ has a normal group $Y$ so $[X: Y]=4$.

How should I prove this theorem?

Comment: You should verify that it is a subgroup and that it is normal. Finally, you should figure out how big it is, so you can calculate its index.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (sketch):

(a) How can we relate X to some group we are familiar with? Prove that $X\cong S_3\times S_3$.

Let $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ be the set of elements in $S_6$ and let $S_1$ and $S_2$ denote the set of all even resp. odd numbers in $S$.
Let $f:X\rightarrow S_3\times S_3$, $\sigma\mapsto (\sigma_1,\sigma_2)$, where $\sigma_1=\sigma|_{S_1}$, $\sigma_2=\sigma|_{S_2}$. You can show that $f$ is indeed an isomorphism.

(b) Now, we can calculate the size of Y: $$[X:Y]=\frac{|X|}{|Y|}=\frac{|S_3\times S_3|}{Y}=\frac{6\cdot 6}{|Y|}=4.$$

(c) Take a look at the subgroups of $S_3$ (or, $S_3\times S_3$). Which subgroup would be applicable? According to the required size, $Y$ should be isomorphic to $A_3\times A_3$.